# Passing javascript variable from parent to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I have a variable in my page body like so:

```
<script>
   var myClick = false;
</script>
```

And a jquery ui dialog with iframe content. Now I want to check the variable on jquery ui dialog like -

```
<script>
   if(myClick == true){
      // code somthing
   }
</script>
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Nothing is simple when dealing with iFrames. Do anything to avoid them at all. If you want to pass a variable into the frame, you could add them as a parameter of your iFrame url. Maybe this gives you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is on the same domain you can use `window.parent.myClick`

```
if (window.parent.myClick === true) {
  // code somthing
}
```

See [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/U6v3tavrzQrCc03KcDFP?p=preview)